# Jira integration with Jenkins: Raise one bug on Jira per Jenkins job build failure

Tags: jenkins, jira, jira-integration

I want to integrate Jenkins with Jira so that whenever a build fails, for all the testcases that failed under that build for the first time (a regression), then a single bug (issue) should be raise on Jira. In this bug (issue) all the testcases that failed in the build should be present. I don't want a separate bug raised for every test case failure.

Note that the plugin [JiraTestResultReporter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/JiraTestResultReporter/) can do this but it will create a separate bug (issue) on Jira for every test case that is failing.
From the documentation of [JiraTestResultReporter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/JiraTestResultReporter/) :

> If you check the Auto raise issue check box, this plugin will create and link issues for all the failing tests in new builds that don't already have linked issues

Is there any way to use  JiraTestResultReporter so that it will raise only 1 bug on Jira per Jenkins build failure.

Comment: Hi Shubham, this question may be closed as it is not directly a programming related question, in terms of getting a quick answer it would be best to contact the plugin developers directly. You can review already logged issues here  https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64295?jql=text%20~%20jiratestresultreporter-plugin%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC Hope this helps!

Comment: @RobKielty Is it possible to add the above requirement as a 'improvement' or something there? [jenkins issue tracking](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64295?jql=text%20~%20jiratestresultreporter-plugin%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC)

Comment: Not sure if the top off my head would have to do some digging to find out. Given that your requirement is possibly a fundamental design change it would be best to just ask first. ....

Comment: But if you are highly motivated you could go down the path of implementing your own plugin to do this or invoking the JIRA API using curl in a separate step post your build.

Comment: @RobKielty I have to use Jira REST API for this matter. I was hoping if there is any shortcut.

Comment: Using a https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuild-task/ and using curl to interact with the Jira API would get you up and running very quickly

Comment: @RobKieltyThis is actually helpful! Thanks!!

Comment: I should have said this at the outset :)